# auto completion of cedet doesn't work if I use ac-source-semantic instead of ac-source-semantic-raw

Tags: emacs, cedet

I have set up an c/c++ IDE according to this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ib914gNr0ys). Everything works ok except that the auto completion of cedet didn't work.

After googling a lot, this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860526/3824053) helped my.

So, I don't know where I am wrong? Auto completion in that video actually works properly, but the same configuration does't doesn't work for me.

I use emacs version 24.5 running on Mac OSX 10.10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot but still failed. I now use company instead of auto-completion, it works fine and stably.